# send php variable as a array in php to js file, then echo it every variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I have table which is every row has button to show more detail data based on data row user click (using datatables), the process is I use ajax to pass data from js file to php file then in that php file after some process which is generating an a array return it again to js then echo the array 1 by 1..

I succeed passing a variable to childdatatatable.php using ajax from datatablescript.js.

but I still cant figure how to pass back the array I generate from childdatatatable.php to datatablescript.js and show it (via alert or echo or anything)

sry for bad english..

here's code :

transactions.php

```
<table id="transactiontable" class="table table-striped table-bordered display" cellspacing="0" width="99%">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th width="4%"></th>
         <th width="4%">Order Date</th>
         <th width="10%">ID Transaksi</th>
         <th width="7%">User ID</th>
         <th width="9%">Total</th>
         <th width="5%">Status</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <?php
         $query = mysqli_query($koneksi, "select * from penjualan order by tanggal desc");
         while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
         ?>
      <tr data-child-value="<?php echo $data['no_pen'];?>" id="<?=($data['no_pen'])?>">
         <td class="details-control"></td>
         <td>
            <center><?php echo $data['tanggal']; ?></center>
         </td>
         <td>
            <center><?php echo $data['no_pen']; ?></center>
         </td>
         <td>
            <center><?php echo $data['id_usr']; ?></center>
         </td>
         <td>
            <center>Rp. <?php echo number_format($data['jumlah_total'],0,'','.'); ?>,-</center>
         </td>
         <td>
            <center><?php echo $data['status']; ?></center>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <?php } ?>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

datatablescript.js

```
function format(value) {
    var id = value;
    return '<div>Detail Item : ' + value + '</div>';


}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#transactiontable').DataTable({});

    // Add event listener for opening and closing details
    $('#transactiontable').on('click', 'td.details-control', function() {

        var elem = $(this),
            selecteditem = elem.val(),
            id = elem.closest('tr').attr('id');

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "childdatatable.php",
            data: {
                'id': id
            },
            success: function(data) {
                if (data) {
                    var test = '<?php echo json_encode($brid) ?>';
                    alert(test);

                }

            }
        });
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row(tr);

        if (row.child.isShown()) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        } else {
            // Open this row
            row.child(format(tr.data('child-value'))).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    });
});
```

childdatatatable.php

```
require_once("koneksi.php");
session_start();

    if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
        echo "<script>alert('You must register an account first, we will redirect you to register page !'); window.location = 'registuser.php'</script>";
    }

$no_pen = $_POST['id']; 
$query = "SELECT br_id from item_penjualan where penjualan_id = '$no_pen'";

if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($koneksi,$query))
    {
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,$brid);

        while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
            printf ($brid);
        }
        json_encode($brid);
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }
```

Comment: A webserver won't (normally) run any PHP inside a `.js` file - it just sends it straight to the client as-is. It's generally a bad idea to mix the two anyway, because then the js can't get cached. Instead, in your .php page, add something like `<script>var myData=<?php echo json_encode($brid); ?>;</script>` and use `myData` from your .js file.

Comment: so it like change variable to js type before send to js file right ?

Answer (score 0):

@`childdatatatable.php` after you encode your array, echo it.

```
echo json_encode($brid);
```

Also: [printf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) is a wasted line, right?  I mean, you aren't doing any formatting to `$brid`.

@`datatablescript.js` you can tell .js to expect and decode your json like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "childdatatable.php",
    data: {'id': id},
    success: function(data){
        if(data){
            var test = data;
            //alert(test);
        }
    },
    dataType:"json"
});
```

Comment: @GustiAldi if my answer solves your issue, please award it a green tick (and possibly upvote it as helpful).  Otherwise, please explain what needs to be fixed.